# 1970s or 80s kids book: girl's life taken over by a robot doppelganger version of herself

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, androids

I read this book between 1980-82 but it could have been written earlier.

It's about a girl who is dissatisfied with her life, as her parents have her on a diet and she wants to be able to eat what she wants. Someone offers her a solution: to come live in this large building where she can eat all the chocolate eclairs and other junkfood she wants, while a robot doppelganger android version of herself will take her place at home and at school.

The girl agrees, but finds that after week of eating mainly eclairs, she is sick and wants to eat a decent meal. But she is not allowed to eat anything else and has found herself to be a prisoner, so she sets out to get rid of the android and get her life back.

I don't recall the ending but it seemed the 'people' behind it all might have been aliens and the building might have been a kind of ship that then disappears.

Comment: How long you think the book would have been? I searched on worldcat.org for double and robot and found this: https://www.worldcat.org/title/double/oclc/27588213 but it seems quite short.

Comment: Thanks for looking. It wasn't that short I don't think, I'd say more like a novel length.. at least 100 pages.. probably was YA rather than children's (technically) though I got it from my elementary school library at the time, I was in the 5th grade so would have been reading the most advanced level books they would have carried (I always was way above my reading level anyway!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like [Is There Life on a Plastic Planet?](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1870324.Is_There_Life_on_a_Plastic_Planet_) by Mildred Ames. According to the [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/1976/02/15/archives/is-there-life-on-a-plastic-planet.html):

> Overweight, overscheduled Hollis and her cousin Addison trade places in their daily routine with programmed dolldoubles, manufactured by the strange Eudora—but when they try to switch back, the pair realize they are trapped.

Comment: Thank you! YES! You found it!! I did not think I or anyone would, I'd given up on it at this point, so I really appreciate your finding this!!! Perfect, thank you!!

Comment: @Shannon You should accept this answer with the check mark button then. :)

Comment: Thanks, hadn't noticed that, was wondering how to approve it! :) Thanks again so much for your help. I now have the book on order from Amazon. :)