# Children's novel where girl agrees to be replaced by robot/clone

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

This was a children's or YA novel I read in the 80s or 90s, I think relatively recent at the time.  Written in English.

Sent in the present day (as was), a girl is fed up with her life and accepts an offer from a woman to replace her with a robot or clone that will do things like go to school for her.

The woman provides a place for the girl to stay when the robot is impersonating her, the place has all her favourite things to eat, which include chocolate eclairs.  Eventually she comes into conflict with the woman and robot trying to get her life back.

Comment: This is most likely the same book as [1970s or 80s kids book: girl's life taken over by a robot doppelganger version of herself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/216820/98028). If you confirm, we can mark this question as a duplicate of an existing answer, to point future readers and searchers to the correct answer straight away :)

Comment: Yep - that's the one - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this might be *[Is There Life on a Plastic Planet?](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1870324.Is_There_Life_on_a_Plastic_Planet_)* (1975) by Mildred Ames, as per [this previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/222264).

> Feeling pressured and unhappy in her everyday life, a young girl welcomes the opportunity of having a look-alike life-size doll take her place at school and at home.

The synopsis from Goodreads was pretty short, so here's [a review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/a/mildred-ames/is-there-life-on-a-plastic-planet/) to add a bit more info on the plot:

> Hollis Brewster, overweight and pushed toward over-achievement by an overstructured mother, is caught up in a world of children's lib when she finds a shop of living dolls run by another living doll (literally, it turns out) called Ms. Eudora--the kind of person she'd always imagined as a big sister. **Convinced that she is participating in an ""important scientific experiment,"" Hollis permits Eudora and company to construct a lifelike mechanical model of herself to replace her in school and at all the other places she finds unendurable (dancing lessons, piano lessons, etc.).** Complications arise when her ""wretched cousin"" Addison, a show-off whose lack of direction and control is as frustrating as Hollis' scheduled life, discovers the daily switch between Hollis and the doll and joins in the game. **The constant diet of sweets and the insipid ""friends"" provided at the shop eventually pale, and Hollis wants to return to her rightful place, but the Hollis doll refuses to yield. In the end it is emotion that conquers the doll,** and by then clever kids will have figured out that Ms. Eudora, the ""friends,"" and everyone involved in the shop are automatons. While the message about the creation of robots by programming parents may or may not hit home, youngsters will probably have fun with this.